# check checkbox one by one with one button

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I have 8 checkboxes in my form and one button, what i need is:

For each button click i want each of checkbox to be checked one by one.
for example:

```
first click 

checkbox1.checked = true
checkbox2.checked = false
checkbox3.checked = false
checkbox4.checked = false
```

second click

```
checkbox1.checked = true
checkbox2.checked = true
checkbox3.checked = false
checkbox4.checked = false
```

third click

```
checkbox1.checked = true
checkbox2.checked = true
checkbox3.checked = true
checkbox4.checked = false
```

Can someone help me if this is possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: what happens for the 4th and 5th click? what have you tried, where is some code?  What happens if the user has already checked some?

Comment: Button is being clicked, checkboxes are not visible. It doesnt matter what order is it, preferably 1 then 2 then 3 etc.

Comment: Ahhh!  using UI controls as variables?  bad idea.

Comment: Am just learning Visual Basic controls,  

If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
            CheckBox1.Checked = True
        Else
            If CheckBox2.Checked = False Then
                CheckBox2.Checked = True
            End If
            End If
seem to work okay

Answer (score 0):

Well, because I was curious on how to do this myself when I read this, I came up with this:

***NOTE: This is probably not the best way to do this, but it does function.***

***NOTE: What you want to accomplish is very strange, but making the logic on how to do this, you can do yourself I assume.***

CODE:

```
public sub fun()
dim doOnce as Boolean = False

'Loop Through all Controls in the Form    
For Each control in Mybase.Controls

'Check if the type of control is a CheckBox
    If control.GetType.Tostring = "System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox" Then
        If doOnce = False Then
            If control.Checked = false Then
                control.Checked = True
                doOnce = true
            else
                control.Checked = False
            End if
        End If
    End If
Next

end sub
```

Hopefully this helps you in some sort of way.
Although I have to say that this idea is not going to learn you much, other than how to point at some controls (And maybe I didn't even show you the best way).

EDIT:
As I just noticed myself this does not go From 'CheckBox1' to 'CheckBox4' (For example). It moves exactly the other way around. Why this is, I am not sure.

Comment: why not just use a `for each` and iterate through the controls ofType(of Checkbox)`? then if checked = false, set it to true and exit the loop. 5 or 6 lines of code.

Comment: I did use a 'for each' and I did check the Type (Did not use a method if that is what you mean), and about exiting the loop, Yes I could have done that a better way, but was not sure what the exact goal was that he wanted to reach.

Comment: the last control to be placed in the controls collection is the first one the for each sees. Using my method you could just add reverse()

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea if you just answer the question with a code example. Makes this much easier I think. But I do agree with you.

Comment: I don't want to answer unless the OP has made an attempt. What I'm talking about is `For Each chk As CheckBox in Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()` this will get only the checkboxes in the collection saving you from having to ensure you have the correct control type with each iteration.

Comment: That is a great idea! It does make things a lot easier and efficient.